# How to get working logs of an genexus app on tomcat7

Tags: genexus

I cant get logs from my app.

```
added in WEB-INF/lib/

gxclassD.jar
gxclassp.jar
gxclassr.jar
```

in client.cfg added where to log.

```
client.cfg:JDBC_LOG=/usr/share/tomcat/logs/jdbc.log
```

but I get nothing.

Im trying it opn tomcat7 on opensuse 13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding the following to your client.cfg

```
JDBC_LOG= /usr/share/tomcat/logs/jdbc.log
JDBCLogEnabled=1
JDBCUniqueName=0
JDBCLogBuffer=0
JDBCLogDetail=0
```

You may need to play around with the JDBCLogDetail value to fit your needs.
That should do the trick, never tried it though...